# How does it make sense that lengths can be expressed using numbers?

Tags: geometry

In physics, lengths and distances are described using a unit of measure and a constant ($4$ meters, $5$ inches, $10^{53}$ planck lengths). In mathematics, we describe space without units. How are numbers and lengths related? What does it mean, for example, for a side of a triangle to have the length $l=2$?

Comment: It is just leaving the user of the application the freedom to choose whatever unit he wants. In some sense, it can be viewed as a choice of a unit without name. It indicates that all the measures are always relative numbers! When you say one meter, you are just deciding that the length of a given object is fixed as one meter, and the other objects are measured relatively to it.

Comment: This is perhaps even more clear when you do computer programming. At the end, the length of a window in a website for example will depend on the size of the screen of the user. So length are once again defined relatively. A length of $1/2$ will for example correspond to one half of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It means that with don't care about the units. For instance, if the lengths of the sides of a triangle are $3$, $4$, and $5$, then its area is $6$. And this is universal, in the sense that if the lengths were measured in meters, then the area is measured in square meters. And if the lengths were measured in miles, then the area is measured in square miles.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, if you want to talk about lenghts and distances between points, you consider the set $X$ to which the points belong, equipped with a function $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ satysfying the following properties:

- $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$
- $d(x,y)+d(x,z)\geq d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z\in X$

After that, distances are just members of $\mathbb{R}$, and you can perform on them all the operations allowed in an ordered field.